# How to prevent the style added to anchors from footer in JQueryMobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have this html code:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <a id="info">About - Settings</a>
</div>
```

JqueryMobile will style that "a" as a button because its inside the footer:

[image]

This is the css added by the framework:

```
<a id="page/idinfo" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-role="button" role="button">About</a>
```

How can I prevent the styling to that button?

This is what I need:

[image]

I know I could try some javascript to remove the class from the anchor, but maybe JQueryMobile has something to prevent that styling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using jqm 1.4?

Comment: yes, thanks. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: You can use this solution as well http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vyUpd/ for different elements not only anchors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a dara-role="none":

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
    <span data-role="none"> <a id="info">About - Settings</a></span>
</div>
```

In jQM 1.4 the data-role="none" seems to need to be on a container, in 1.3 you can apply it directly to the anchor tag.

Comment: thanks ezanker! I tried with data-role="none" before with no success. In JQM 1.4 it needs to be inside a container as you say.